# How to set default (instead of nil) variable initialization for all instances in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Where is instance variable initialized as nil first time?
Can I redefine it as other value by default for all instances?

For example:

```
class Class
  #some code here or maybe in an Object class
end

class Foo1
  attr_accessor :bar
end

class Foo2
  attr_accessor :bar
end

p Foo1.new.bar # result is not nil
p Foo2.new.bar # result is not nil
```

This can be done by modifying the reader:

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor(attr_name)
    ...
    define_method "#{attr_name}" do
      if instance_variable_get "@#{attr_name}_history"
        instance_variable_get "@#{attr_name}_history"
      else
        "Not nil"
      end
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

But this doesn't help in understanding the core of Ruby.
Many thanks!

Comment: I would like to express **a clear warning to any new ruby programmer** that might stumble on this question to be cautious. If you feel a desire to change the behavior of such core ruby functionality I advise to reconsider. It makes for bad programming habits and code that is hard to maintain by others. Changing the default value of **all** attributes for **all** classes does not seem very scalable when a piece of code grows in functionality.

Comment: Depending on what you try to do there are probably better alternatives. You might ask the community on advise on how to handle your case (by asking your own question). Make sure to give enough context to explain why you feel overriding core methods like this is your only alternative. You might learn to improve your logic and coding skills on the long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new method in class `Class`. Get instance variables through `:instance_variables` and set them to anything you like by using `:instance_variable_set(:@var,default_value)`

```
class Class

    alias oldNew new
        def new(*args)
        result = oldNew(*args)
        default = 2354 # set default here
        a = result.instance_variables
        a.each do
        |d|
        result.instance_variable_set(d,default)
        end

    return result
    end

end
```

Comment: It's true that this will *work* to do what the OP is asking (and it's a neat trick), but this will likely break a *lot* of other things in the ruby standard library and other gems.

Comment: yup, i agree.
lets add a caution: For Academic And Learning Purposes Only, Side effect involve breaking a lot of thing. But we can name our method something like  'default_new'  instead of 'new' . thus using
'foo = Foo.default_new'

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set default values, you can assign them in an `initialize` method of a class.

For example:

```
class Test

  attr_accessor :bar

  def initialize
    @bar = 'bar'
  end

end

Test.new.bar
# => "bar"
```

Remember that `attr_accessor :bar` gives you helper methods to set and get the underlying instance variable `@bar`.

If you want default values for lots of classes, you can have them inherit from a class that sets the instance variables as not nil:

```
class Foo < Test

end

Foo.new.bar
# => "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

(Corrected following Jörg W Mittag's comment)

No you cannot. Instance variables are <strike>set</strike> evaluated to `nil` when you call them without assigning a value to them.

Comment: The variable isn't set to anything. It is uninitialized. Uninitialized  variables evaluate to `nil`.

Comment: Ok, what is the first place, there cant I initialize variable?
Is it initialize method? Or somewhere before?

Comment: Maybe I can redefine some class method (new)?

Comment: You can define `initialize` so that it assigns something to an instance variable.

Comment: Yes, but that will only change the behavior of one class instances.
There is now way to change this in Class or Object classes?

Comment: It can be done by overriding Class#new method.
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: How is overriding `Class#new` different from defining `initialize` as I wrote? You responded that that does not count as what you wanted. Of course you can do it that way. I already wrote that.

Comment: Because initialize should be defined in each class definition, but Class#new can be overridden only once.